# How to set the column family when inserting a row in Bigtable

Tags: node.js, google-api, insert, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I want to insert a row to Bigtable, I tried this simple code

```js
const rowToInsert = {
  key: `${tenantId}:${customerId}`,
  data: personalInfo
};

await table.insert(rowToInsert);
```

but I got

```js
Error while mutating the row '999:customerId' : Requested column family not found.
```

The column family exists, so how can I set the column family for this insertion?
I saw [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Table.html#insert) example in the documentation and it's not clear to me

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Bigtable [Writing Data documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data#node.js) shows how to perform various writes

```
data: {
  [COLUMN_FAMILY_ID]: {
    [COLUMN_QUALIFIER]: {
      // Setting the timestamp allows the client to perform retries. If
      // server-side time is used, retries may cause multiple cells to
      // be generated.
      timestamp: new Date(),
      value: greeting,
    },
  },
},
```